# How to get a string to split into chunks of five?

Tags: python, string, chunking

So the program would read a file with a string. That string would then be saved to another file but the string would be split into groups of 5.

Example.

Given that the content of `file1.txt` will be `thecatsatonthemat`, the content of `file2.txt` would then be `theca tsato nthem at`.

Comment: How about writing some code yourself? If you'll encounter a specific problem we'll be happy to help.

Comment: This is the specific problem

Answer (score 7):

Here is an enumerator that will give you 5 character chunks:

```
def chunk(l):
    for i in range(0, len(l), 5):
        yield l[i:i+5]
```

Use it like:

```
>>> l = 'abcdefghijqlmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> for sub in chunk(l):
>>>     print(sub)

abcde
fghij
klmno
pqrst
uvwxy
z
```

Comment: Grats, your answer is listed below (:
https://github.com/drathier/stack-overflow-import

Comment: In Python 2, replace `range` with `xrange` to avoid creating long temporary lists if the input is long.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, e.g. the OP specified that input should be read from a file.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
>>> a = "123456789012345678901234567890"
>>> while len(a)>0:
...     print a[0:5]
...     a=a[5:]
...
12345
67890
12345
67890
12345
67890
```

Comment: This is very slow (`O(len(a)**2)`) for long strings, because `a[5:]' makes a copy of almost the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Contents of file data.txt `thecatsatonthemat`

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
new_string = ''
for i,val in enumerate(data):
    if i%5 == 0 and i != 0:
        new_string += ' ' + val
    else:
        new_string += val
with open('new_data.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_string)
```

Contents of new_data.txt

```
theca tsato nthem at
```

Comment: This is incorrect, it adds an extra space to the beginning of `new_data.txt`.

Comment: @pts: Corrected the solution. The use of lstrip() will remove the space at the beginning of string

Comment: It's still incorrect, because lstrip removes additional spaces when the input starts with spaces.

Comment: @pts: Updated the solution

Comment: The solution is now correct. It reads the entire input file to memory, so it uses `O(n)` memory if the file size is `n`. See my solution with less (`O(1)`) memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. `file1.txt` will be the file where the string is retrieved. `file2.txt` will be the file where the split string will be written.

**NOTE: This code assumes that the text file (file1.txt) doesn't have white spaces or newlines.**

```
line = ''
with open('file1.txt', 'r') as fr:
    line = fr.read()
fr.close()

modified_str = ''
for i in range(0, len(line), 5):
    modified_str += line[i:i + n] + ' '
modified_str = modified_str[:len(modified_str) - 1] # Remove the trailing white space

with open('file2.txt', 'w') as fw:
    fw.write(modified_str)
fw.close()
```

Let us assume that the contents of `file1.txt` is `thecatsatonthemat`. Running that code, `file2.txt` will now contain `theca tsato nthem at`.

Comment: This doesn't work, it raises `NameError: name 'n' is not defined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the string in memory and you need the output in memory, use Steven Burnap's answer.

If you need to read and write files, here is a fast solution which uses little (`O(1)`) memory, and works in Python 2 and 3:

```
with open('file1.txt') as f:
  with open('file2.txt', 'w') as nf:
    item = f.read(5)
    nf.write(item)
    while len(item) == 5:
      item = f.read(5)
      if not item:
        break
      nf.write(' ')
      nf.write(item)
```